# Nginx Client_max_body_size not able to solve

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have nginx issue. I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy and nodejs as the backend and Mongodb as the DB. From few days I am getting a weird error says too large body. I inserted client_max-body_size and to 10m, But still couldn't able to solve the issue.  please tell me where I did wrong 
`2017/09/11 23:46:40 [error] 39158#39158: *156474 client intended to send too large body: 3356812 bytes, client: 10.150.98.84, server: example.com, request: "POST /api/sensors HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"`

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    index   index.html index.htm;
upstream nodejs {
    server localhost:3000;
}
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.com;


location / {
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ @nodejs;
    }

    location @nodejs {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header Host $host ;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
    }
location ~ (/images|/img|/javascript|/js|/css|/stylesheets|/flash|/media|/static|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico){
root /var/www/app/public;
client_max_body_size 10M;
}
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding it to `location /{` block?

Comment: I have one question. So I need to add in to location /{ block and remove the client_max_body_size 10M from other places ..?

Comment: I believe yes because the request is landing first there and then being checked at `@nodejs`, so currently it is getting rejected earlier before reaching to nodejs

Comment: So hopefully this will work. This is what you say bro ..?                                                               
`location / {
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ @nodejs;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
    } `

Comment: Yes. Later you can restrict this for `/api/sensors` endpoint if that is the only one expecting such a large body

Comment: Ok lemme try this and I dont want any downtime. So I am going to restart the nginx with `sudo service nginx reload` command .

Comment: Yes that should not be a problem.

Comment: Hi tarun, Can I know how can we restrict for /api/sensors only..?

Answer (score 0):

Add a specific location block for `/api/sensors` and increase the limit for same

```
location /api/sensors {
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    try_files dummy_file_not_exists @nodejs;
}
```

This way you only expose the endpoint with large body which expects to receive it. Do test it locally before putting on production.

Comment: Thanks. Does it work without adding a specific block for /api/sensors ..? I mean does it really needed to add a extra block for /api/sensors ..?

Comment: That is more like a protection. You can add to `location /` and it would work. But the increases your attach surface area where one can send a 10MB while requesting any resource